# How to map docker default IP address to Domain name

Tags: php, docker

I have setup my Drupal using the Docker and accessing my sites through ip . But now i want to map docker IP address to some domain name in my local machine . can anyone please help me. something like this: Ex : http://192.160.168.3 to http://mysites

Comment: What registrar was your domain purchased through?

Comment: I want this in my local machine.

Comment: That's fine, but you have to register a domain for that to work.

Comment: yes you are right , still i have not registered a domain. first i want this in my local env ,and then i will go for domain registration.

Comment: You can't map a domain that you don't own to your local website. For now, you will have to connect to your site via your IP or localhost.

Comment: For local connection only, you can modify your [hosts file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266483/editing-hosts-file-to-redirect-url) I.e. 127.0.0.1 -> google.com. When you go to google.com it gos to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Create the local host name as

```
sudo echo "127.0.0.1 mysite.local" >> /etc/hosts
```

Now you can redirect to your application with mysite.local